# What is the relation of Permittivity of free space (ε₀) with esu unit of charge in cgs system?

Tags: speed-of-light, charge, coulombs-law, si-units, unit-conversion

In the CGS system the Coulombs law is defined as $F=\frac{Qq}{r^2}$ with the constant $k=1$ which was equal to $\frac{1}{4\piε_0}$ in the MKS system.

The thing that allows this equation to be valid is that the charge here is defined as $1\text{esu} = (\frac{1}{10c})$Coulombs where c is the magnitude of speed of light ie.  $2.99792458 \cdot 10^8\frac{m}{s}$, along with force in dynes and r in cm.

I wish to know why or how is cgs system defined in this manner. This also gives constant $k$ of MKS system to be related to c, as in 
$k=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=\frac{c^2}{10^7}$.

Surely this has some meaning to it. I have no clue of the origin of this and would very much like to know the reason behind the relation.

Comment: Check the *units* of $\epsilon_0$ and the units of $c^2$. You’ll find that your last equation isn’t true.

Comment: You went wrong when you said that $1$ esu “equals” $1/(10c)$ coulombs.

Comment: The right way to define 1 esu is that two point charges of 1 esu separated by 1 centimeter have an electrostatic repulsion of 1 dyne.

Comment: The last equation is only meant for showing magnitude. My doubt is, If esu is indeed defined as stated above then how does magnitude of speed of light come into the equations. Why the number 299792458?

Comment: The reasons for that are of historical interest only. (You can start trying to understand them by looking at the magnetic constant $\mu_0$ and its relationship with $\epsilon_0$ and $c$.) SI units for EM are hideous historical monstrosities. On my opinion, there is no reason to waste neurons trying to make them seem sensible. I am a huge fan of Gaussian units with $k=1$.